# group action on a fiber bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, fibration

I am in the following situation,

Let $F \rightarrow E \xrightarrow{p} B$ be a fiber bundle and suppose that we have a group $G$ acting freely on $E$ and $B$, satisfying $p(g\cdot x) = g \cdot p(x)$; thus we have a well defined map

$\overline{p}: E/G \rightarrow B/G$, my question is: is that map a fiber bundle with fiber $F$?

I have seen this argument, for instance, proving that the borel construction $EG \times_G X \rightarrow BG$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $X$, by applying the above construction to the projection map $EG \times X \rightarrow EG$.

So, is that a general result or there are some conditions that I am missing

Comment: I think your question has been addressed (at least in part) in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52224/does-the-borel-functor-take-equivariant-fibrations-to-fibrations.

I'll also point to a statement I found in tom Dieck's "Transformation Groups" as Exercise 3.21 on page 121.

Comment: @Tyrone:  I don't currently have access to that book - would you mind writing out the statement?

Comment: @JasonDeVito, it's too long for me to reasonably type, but the relevant parts of the book are available on google books.

Comment: Tyrone:  I looked on google books and got the "these pages are not part of the preview" issue.  Anyway, I will try to get my hands on a copy.  I feel that the OPs question must be true in general, but haven't been able to figure out a proof...